# Set Task User Type with URL Hack

Tags: user, tasks, urlhacking, userlicense

I am working on creating a custom button that creates a task that has been prepopulated using url hacking. I've gotten almost all of my fields to work, but I am stuck on how to get the "Assigned To" field to change from the "User" type to the "Customer Portal User" type (see pictures below for reference).

From this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

My current URL code is as follows:

```
https://na88.salesforce.com/00T/e?
&tsk1={!Matriculation__c.Student__c}
&tsk1_lkid={!Matriculation__c.Student_User_ID__c}
&tsk2={!Matriculation__c.Student__c}
&tsk3_mlktp=a05
&tsk3={!Matriculation__c.Name}
&00Ni000000HXWGN="Finance"
&00Ni000000HXWGU=1
```

How can I set to "Assigned to" picklist value to "Customer Portal User"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your `tsk1_mlktp` value to be `&tsk1_mlktp=CustomerSuccessUserLookup`.

You can find this using the developer tools in Chrome. If you right click the `<select>` and click `Inspect Element`, you can view the children `<option>`'s and see what value corresponds with the label you want selected.